# Hibernate error: found shared references

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Found
>   shared references to a collection:
>   sabeja.entity.ClassificatorObject.apartmentPayers; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a
>   collection: sabeja.entity.ClassificatorObject.apartmentPayers

I have been searching solution for 2 days. I found solutions in the stackoverflow, but they didn't help for me. I disabled parts of code, but I haven't caught problem.

ClassificatorObject Entity

```
package xm.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="managment_responsibilities_object")
public class ClassificatorObject implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="responsibility_id")
    private int responsibilityId;

    @Column(name="object_id")
    private int objectId; 

    @Column(name="is_enabled")
    private int isEnabled;

    @Column(name="by_area")
    private int byArea; 

    @Column(name="by_people")
    private int byPeople; 

    @Column(name="by_flat")
    private int byFlat; 

    @Column(name="is_general")
    private int isGeneral;

    @Column(name="sort")
    private int sort;

    @Column(name="not_counting")
    private int notCounting;

//  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "classificatorObject", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//  @OrderBy("month")
//  private Set<ServicePeriod> periods;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Set<ServiceOption> options;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    //@JoinColumn(name = "service_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "object_id", 
            referencedColumnName = "object_id",
            insertable=false, updatable=false
        )

    private Set<ApartmentPayer> apartmentPayers;



    public Set<ApartmentPayer> getApartmentPayers() {
        return apartmentPayers;
    }

    public void setApartmentPayers(Set<ApartmentPayer> apartmentPayers) {
        this.apartmentPayers = apartmentPayers;
    }



    @Column(name="parent_service_id")
    private int parentServiceId;

    @Column(name="has_children")
    private int hasChildren;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="responsibility_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Classificator classificator;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_service_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ClassificatorObject parentService;



//CONSTRUCTORS: 

    public ClassificatorObject() {
    }

    public ClassificatorObject(int responsibilityId, int objectId, int isEnabled, int byArea, int byPeople, int byFlat,
            int isGeneral, int sort, int notCounting, Set<ServicePeriod> periods, Set<ServiceOption> options,
            int parentServiceId, int hasChildren, Classificator classificator) {
        super();
        this.responsibilityId = responsibilityId;
        this.objectId = objectId;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        this.byArea = byArea;
        this.byPeople = byPeople;
        this.byFlat = byFlat;
        this.isGeneral = isGeneral;
        this.sort = sort;
        this.notCounting = notCounting;
    //  this.periods = periods;
        this.options = options;
        this.parentServiceId = parentServiceId;
        this.hasChildren = hasChildren;
        this.classificator = classificator;
    }

//GETTERS SETTERS:

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getResponsibilityId() {
        return responsibilityId;
    }

    public void setResponsibilityId(int responsibilityId) {
        this.responsibilityId = responsibilityId;
    }

    public int getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(int objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public int getIsEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsEnabled(int isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public int getByArea() {
        return byArea;
    }

    public void setByArea(int byArea) {
        this.byArea = byArea;
    }

    public int getByPeople() {
        return byPeople;
    }

    public void setByPeople(int byPeople) {
        this.byPeople = byPeople;
    }

    public int getByFlat() {
        return byFlat;
    }

    public void setByFlat(int byFlat) {
        this.byFlat = byFlat;
    }

    public int getIsGeneral() {
        return isGeneral;
    }

    public void setIsGeneral(int isGeneral) {
        this.isGeneral = isGeneral;
    }

    public int getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public void setSort(int sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public int getNotCounting() {
        return notCounting;
    }


    public void setNotCounting(int notCounting) {
        this.notCounting = notCounting;
    }

//  public Set<ServicePeriod> getPeriods() {
//      return periods;
//  }
//
//  public void setPeriods(Set<ServicePeriod> periods) {
//      this.periods = periods;
//  }

    public Set<ServiceOption> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(Set<ServiceOption> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public int getParentServiceId() {
        return parentServiceId;
    }

    public void setParentServiceId(int parentServiceId) {
        this.parentServiceId = parentServiceId;
    }   

    public int getHasChildren() {
        return hasChildren;
    }

    public void setHasChildren(int hasChildren) {
        this.hasChildren = hasChildren;
    }

    public Classificator getClassificator() {
        return classificator;
    }

    public void setClassificator(Classificator classificator) {
        this.classificator = classificator;
    }   



    public ClassificatorObject getParentService() {
        return parentService;
    }

    public void setParentService(ClassificatorObject parentService) {
        this.parentService = parentService;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassificatorObject [id=" + id + ", responsibilityId=" + responsibilityId + ", objectId=" + objectId
                + ", isEnabled=" + isEnabled + ", byArea=" + byArea + ", byPeople=" + byPeople + ", byFlat=" + byFlat
                + ", isGeneral=" + isGeneral + ", sort=" + sort + ", notCounting=" + notCounting + ", parentServiceId="
                + parentServiceId + ", hasChildren=" + hasChildren + "]";
    }

}
```

ApartmentPayer Entity

```
package sabeja.entity;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="sb_flat_payers")
public class ApartmentPayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="flat_id")
    private int flatId;


    @Column(name="payer_id")
    private int payerId;

    @Column(name="object_id")
    private int objectId;

    @Column(name="area", columnDefinition="Decimal(12,2)")
    private BigDecimal area;

    @Column(name="people_number")
    private int peopleNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="flatPayer_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Set<ServiceOption> options;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="payer_id", insertable= false, updatable= false)
    private User user;

//  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//  @JoinColumn(name="object_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
//  private TheObject theObject;

    public ApartmentPayer() {
        super();
    }



    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }



    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



    public Set<ServiceOption> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }



    public void setOptions(Set<ServiceOption> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }



    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public int getFlatId() {
        return flatId;
    }


    public void setFlatId(int flatId) {
        this.flatId = flatId;
    }


    public int getPayerId() {
        return payerId;
    }


    public void setPayerId(int payerId) {
        this.payerId = payerId;
    }




    public BigDecimal getArea() {
        return area;
    }



    public void setArea(BigDecimal area) {
        this.area = area;
    }



    public int getPeopleNumber() {
        return peopleNumber;
    }



    public void setPeopleNumber(int peopleNumber) {
        this.peopleNumber = peopleNumber;
    }


    public int getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }



    public void setObjectId(int objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }


//  public TheObject getTheObject() {
//      return theObject;
//  }
//
//
//
//  public void setTheObject(TheObject theObject) {
//      this.theObject = theObject;
//  }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApartmentPayer [id=" + id + ", flatId=" + flatId + ", payerId=" + payerId + ", area=" + area
                + ", peopleNumber=" + peopleNumber + "]";
    }

}
```

DAOIMPL

```
Query<Apartment> queryResult2 = currentSession
                .createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Apartment a "
                        + "JOIN FETCH a.theObject o "
                        + "JOIN FETCH o.services s "
                        + "JOIN FETCH s.apartmentPayers ap "
                    //  + "LEFT JOIN FETCH s.options op "
                    //  + "JOIN ServicePeriod p ON s.id = p.responsibilities_object_id "
                    //  + "JOIN FETCH ap.user u "
                        + "WHERE a.houseId = :object_id "
                    //  + "AND (op.flatPayerId = ap.id OR op.id is NULL) "
                        //+ "AND (SELECT count(*) FROM DisabledPayer di WHERE  di.serviceId = s.id AND di.flatPayerId = ap.id) = 0"
            //  + "AND (CASE WHEN op.is_disabled = 0 THEN 1 WHEN op.is_disabled = 1 "
            //  + "THEN 0  END) = 1) OR op.id IS NULL"
                , Apartment.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can happen in some specific cases when you have kind of a 'loop' reference, but in this case you don't have a class with a field that uses this same class.

So the error has to be in a call to the method `setApartmentPayers()`, you need to check all the calls to the method and ensure that you are not assigning the same collection to two different entities.